# Transfer Function of Differential opamp with common mode voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, common-mode, differential-amplifier

When we consider the relationship between Vout and Vin of the differential amplifier, we connect one of its inputs each time to the ground to ignore that input voltage in the calculation, in order to calculate the transfer function between another input and Vout. After we get all the transfer functions between each input and Vout, we can sum up all of them to get a complete output response by applying the superposition theorem.
[image]

As a result, the transfer function of this opamp:

[image]

What I don't get is this transfer function considering common-mode voltage:

[image]

***V2 now is the common mode voltage in the third equation.

This article, https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/the-differential-amplifier-common-mode-error-part-1/, ignores the contribution of another input (the real voltage input 2) to the output. How could this be possible? What exactly is the subtraction of V1 and common voltage, "V1 - V2" in the first term?

Comment: It's not clear to me. But are you thinking about something [like this](https://pages.hmc.edu/mspencer/e151/sp21/notes/20.pdf)?

Comment: "Common mode" voltage is coefficient of (V1+V2)/2 ...

Answer (score 0):

If you plug my bottom four equations into my top equation and then multiply out you should find that four of the terms cancel out leaving your original (top) equation.

[image: Derivation]

Comment: Posts consisting of mostly images are not very flexible, have limited readability, do not format according to site style, etc.. Have you taken a look at [Markdown and LaTeX formatting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)?

Comment: @user350400 Where do the top and second formulas come from?

Comment: @TSLee Can't remember where I first saw them, just something I've learned along the way.